# How do i convert KeyPressevents keychar to virtual key code

Tags: c#, wpf, pinvoke, user-input, user32

I am writing a WPF app that allows a user to press a key on their keyboard and then store the virtual key code for later execution
currently, my code only captures the KeyChar

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
        {


            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Key char : " + e.Key);

        }
```

At a later stage, the code is executed, in something similar to this...

```
else if(e.Result.Text.Equals("windows"))
            {
                //windows key down
                keybd_event((byte)VK_LWIN, 0x5B, 0, 0);
                //windows key up
                keybd_event((byte)VK_LWIN, 0x5B, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);

            }
```

The keybd_event method uses virtual key codes to identify which key the program is required to execute on the system.

I can easily capture and execute these separate variables

but how do I convert the keyChar to Virtual key code for storing and then executing in the separate window?

User 32 DLL method..
https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.keybd_event

Answer (score 1):

You can us the [`KeyInterop`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyinterop(v=vs.110).aspx) class. This contains static methods to convert between .Net Keys and VKeys:

```
int vkey;

private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    vkey = System.Windows.Input.KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey(e.Key);
    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Key char : " + e.Key);

}

{
    keybd_event((byte)vkey, 0x5B, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: i added your code, which outputs the number "75" for the key "k"
That isn't what the true value is?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: yes you are incorrect ;) As your link says, the "k" key is 0x4B in hex = 4*16+11 = 75

Comment: so the keybd_event uses ASCII not Hex?

Comment: very likely it is based on ASCII, I don't know for sure, but the virtual keys are numbers and `keybd_event ` takes an number (byte). The numeric representation of 75 in decimal (75) and hex (0x4B)  both mean the same thing, and it is all stored in bytes anyway - 01001011